# Testing a code snippet with valgrind

Tags: c, ubuntu, profiling, valgrind, perf

How can I test a particular part of my program using valgrind(and perf, if the same principles apply)? I'm asking this because perf ./progname tests the whole program.

I cannot remove the other parts because the part I need to test depends on them.

Thanks

Comment: yes, sorry about that

Comment: Didn't know if that was a new term I'd never heard of.

Comment: cool, what about the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run part of a program under Valgrind; Valgrind is an all or nothing affair.

What you can do is to tell it to ignore errors you aren't interested in (because they're in a part of the program you can't fix, for example). To do this, check the Valgrind Suppression Howto: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

This won't speed anything up though, so if speed is your motiviation, this won't help.